# MySQL DB stuck with constantly rolling back transaction but no associated query

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, transaction, aws-aurora

Ran into a problem on a website with a very slow site and tracked it down to the database responding very slowly, even for simple select queries. There seems to be spikes of activity every 9-12 minutes. I did some research and I think I have it narrowed down to a transaction that that gets rolled back and it has a long history length so it takes 9-12 min for the rollback.

What I have been unable to do is figure out what is causing this transaction as it does not seem to have a related query. I have turned on slow query logging, but the queries that are getting logged there are related to being slow because this transaction is being rolled-back and not because they are the ones causing it in the first place.

The symptoms seemed similar to what was described [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/05/08/chasing-a-hung-transaction-in-mysql-innodb-history-length-strikes-back/) but the cause seems different because there was only ever one transaction at a time and it wasnt hung, just taking a long time to roll back.

Any ideas of how I could track this down further?

| **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_METRICS** |  |
| --- | --- |
| **NAME** | trx_rseg_history_len |
| **SUBSYSTEM** | transaction |
| **COUNT** | 4028 |
| **MAX_COUNT** | 4249 |
| **MIN_COUNT** | 3867 |
| **AVG_COUNT** | NULL |
| **COUNT_RESET** | 4028 |
| **MAX_COUNT_RESET** | 4249 |
| **MIN_COUNT_RESET** | 3867 |
| **AVG_COUNT_RESET** | NULL |
| **TIME_ENABLED** | 2021-09-25 01:30:49 |
| **TIME_DISABLED** | NULL |
| **TIME_ELAPSED** | 1790 |
| **TIME_RESET** | NULL |
| **STATUS** | enabled |
| **TYPE** | value |
| **COMMENT** | Length of the TRX_RSEG_HISTORY list |

| **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TRX** |  |
| --- | --- |
| **trx_id** | 50941681 |
| **trx_state** | ROLLING BACK |
| **trx_started** | 2021-09-24 22:20:17 |
| **trx_requested_lock_id** | NULL |
| **trx_wait_started** | NULL |
| **trx_weight** | 53566801 |
| **trx_mysql_thread_id** | 0 |
| **trx_query** | NULL |
| **trx_operation_state** | NULL |
| **trx_tables_in_use** | 0 |
| **trx_tables_locked** | 12 |
| **trx_lock_structs** | 12 |
| **trx_lock_memory_bytes** | 1136 |
| **trx_rows_locked** | 0 |
| **trx_rows_modified** | 53566789 |
| **trx_concurrency_tickets** | 0 |
| **trx_isolation_level** | REPEATABLE READ |
| **trx_unique_checks** | 1 |
| **trx_foreign_key_checks** | 1 |
| **trx_last_foreign_key_error** | NULL |
| **trx_adaptive_hash_latched** | 0 |
| **trx_adaptive_hash_timeout** | 0 |
| **trx_is_read_only** | 0 |
| **trx_autocommit_non_locking** | 0 |

Comment: `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` might help.

Comment: `SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE in_use > 0;` might give a clue.

Comment: did both of those, the proc list everything was sleeping, and there were no open tables

Comment: I did `show engine innodb status` and there are several transactions listed, all as "not started" except for this one: ---TRANSACTION 60893115, ACTIVE 441 sec recovered trx
ROLLING BACK 12 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 5961965

Comment: Sounds useful, did it list some SQL?

Comment: I don't know much about mySQL, but if the rollback of a transaction takes 8-12 minutes, is the transaction being rolled back doing a lot of work over a long period of time?  If so, could the transaction be re-written to do smaller chunks of work and commit more often?

Comment: No SQL listed. That's the main problem in that we dont know what is causing the transaction. Note that `trx_query` above is `NULL`.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever figure out how to solve it?

```---TRANSACTION 845662004, ACTIVE 120786 sec recovered trx
ROLLING BACK 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1128, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 17891594```